# Concurrency with core data

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I am using multi-threading to get data, parse it, create objects and store them. And after this is all done, I want the window to be shown.
But now I have 2 issues:

- I have a deadlock
- My barrier does not act as a barrier.

I think the deadlock is because I am updating the managedObjectContext in several threads at once.

1. So I changed my managedObjectContext with the ConcurrencyType:

   ```
   __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
   ```
2. And created an importContext for the concurrency queue and assigned the parentContext:

   ```
   NSManagedObjectContext *importContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
   importContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
   ```
3. And put my operations in a performBlock for the importContext:

   ```
   [importContext performBlock:^{

     dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
     [myObject methodAWithContext:importContext];
     });

     dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
     [myObject methodBWithContext:importContext];
     });

     dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
     [myObject methodCWithContext:importContext];
     });


     dispatch_barrier_async(backgroundQueueM, ^{
     // create barrier to wait for the first 3 threads to be completed.
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       // Save the data from the importContext tot the main context on the main queue
       NSError *importError = nil;
       [importContext save:&importError];
       [importContext.parentContext performBlock:^{
          NSError *parentError = nil;
          [importContext.parentContext save:&parentError];
       }];

      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

      });
     });
   }];
   ```

Approach 1:
In each method, I select a subset of object, delete these and then create new objects and save this.
(I thought the delete was quicker than doing a fetch and check for the existence for every object to be created).
So:
In Method A I select all AObjects, delete them and create new AObjects.
In Method B I select all BObjects, delete them and create new BObjects.
In Method C I select all CObjects, delete them and create new CObjects.

But then I get an error "An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts".

So approach 2:
I removed the delete. But now I get various different errors..... 
And the barrier does not wait for the other threads to be executed.

Q1: What am I doing wrong?

Q2: how do I get the barrier to wait for the 3 threads to be completed

Q3: how can I delete / purge objects on various threads?

(I have read the Apple release notes and doc's, but I can't find this a clear explanation on the combination for multithreading and managedContext.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call `dispatch_async` within `performBlock`. A managed object context of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` has it's own dispatch queue for executing the operations.

You try to do several operations in parallel by moving them to a different dispatch queue, but that is not possible.

If you really have to do multiple operations in parallel, you must create a private concurrency type MOC for each operation.

**ADDED:**

There are several ways to wait for all operations to complete:

- You could increment a counter at the end of each `performBlock:` and check if it's value is (in your example) 3.
- You could create a semaphore (`dispatch_semaphore_create`) for each operation with initial value zero, wait for all the semaphores (`dispatch_semaphore_wait`) and signal the semaphore at the end of each `performBlock`.
- And I am sure that there are better/more elegant/more sophisticated ways to do this.

**BUT:** As I re-read your question, I see that you try to delay the

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

until all Core Data fetch operations have completed. This is not a good design, because the user will see nothing until your data import is done.

A better design is to show an initial view immediately, and update that view when the background operations have fetched data.

Comment: answer is to close to what I would suggest that just adding a comment. What you need to do is choose one of two solutions. You use the traditional way - you create a serial dispatch queue where you create and do all your MOC work on ((NSConfinementConcurrencyType) - or you ask the MOC to create a queue for you (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) and then ONLY interact with that MOC using performBlock. In either case you can have actions with the MOC in other dispatch blocks, IF AND ONLY IF in the first case you dispatch to your private queue or second you usr [moc performBlock:...].

Comment: Thanx! Now, the concurrency works with 3 seperate MOC's and without the dispatch_async. But now, I still need to know how I can wait for the 3 blocks to be completed before I show my window. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I know, and I am thinking about a better design (however: it is very small data, so it does not take long. But in serial, it takes a few seconds too long. But for the most important part, I have a networkActivityIndicator which is shown, and I want it to be stopped when all data fetching and creation of objects is done.

Comment: And also: in my first design with threads, the view is show, and the subview of the navigationController is shown after the fetching/object creation. But now, it is no longer. The subview is immediately shown. No issue, but I want to let the user know that there is still some activity.

Comment: @RobertvdBerg: I have tried to explain the error in your initial design and also to show some alternatives. You have confirmed that the concurrency works now so you might consider to "accept" the answer.

Comment: @Martin R: excusez-moi. I am new at StackOverflow and I did not know that I should " accept" an answer anywhere, or so soon. Or do you mean that I should not ask additional questions?

Comment: @RobertvdBerg: ... but I may have been a bit too impatient in this case, as the question is only 1 day old. Sorry for that!